# .NET MVC returns error on Count()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a query:

```
foreach (var item in outcomeAreas)
{
    var outcomeAreasCohorts = db.Cohorts
        .Join(db.OutcomeArea, c => c.ID, oa => oa.CohortID, (c, oa) => new { c = c, oa = oa })
        .Where(oa => oa.oa.OutcomeType.Contains(item.SubCategory.ToString()))
        .Select(c => new { c.c.cohortID }).Distinct().ToList().Count();

    allFilters.Add(new GetFilters { Category = item.Category, Identifier = item.Identifier, SubCategory = item.SubCategory, SubCategoryIdentifier = item.SubCategory.ToString().Replace(" ", "-"), TopLevel = "Key Cohort Outcomes", TotalNum = outcomeAreasCohorts.ToString() });
```

}

However, it is throwing an error on me.

```
Values of type 'collection[Edm.String(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=,Unicode=,FixedLength=)]' can not be converted to string.
```

I tried searching, but am not finding this error.  Thoughts?

Comment: Try deleting that entity and adding it back to the edmx. Usually works.

Comment: Do you mean removing it from the class?

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!